# Could - Past or Present - How to identify

Tags: modal-verbs

I know, we can use could to show past capabilities  and future possibilities. But my question is how to identify if it is past or future.

E.g. " He could drive a car."

As per my understanding above sentence can be used to show both past capability and future possibility.

Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Could**" can mean several things in the declarative sentences:

- A very big asteroid **could** wipe out all of humanity. *(possibility)*
- I **could** make you a cake if I had the necessary ingredients. *(conditional)*
- You **could** take it home with you. *(suggestion)*
- He **could** run very fast when he was young. *(past ability)*

As a *past ability* "**could**" is used in place of "**be able to**". As a *possibility* it is used in place of "**may**" or "**might**". As a *conditional* there has to be a **if-clause**.

Answer (score 0):

**Could** is used in present when we want to make a less positive statement about something(future capability) or to make polite request.

Unless tense is clear from context,**could** mean above described stuff.

So, your line in question is in present tense and telling about future capabilities.